# Orientation of featured image in post?

Tags: images, featured-post

Is it possible to show orientation of featured image in post on single.php?

For example:
Orientation of featured image is: portrait / landscape.

---

I have found that this could be done by calculating aspect ratio of image (width / height). For example image with dimensions 1600 x 1200 have aspect ratio 1.33333 (landscape) and 1200 x 1600 have aspect ratio 0.75 (portrait).

If you are interested to find more look on:

[Get total number of pixels, size in megapixels and aspect ratio based on image width and height?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152889/get-total-number-of-pixels-size-in-megapixels-and-aspect-ratio-based-on-image-w)

Comment: What have you already attempted for this, what plugins have you looked at?

Comment: Nothing so far, I have no idea where to start from? Any idea?

Comment: I would assume you would have to add additional metadata to the database when you upload them, allowing you to reference orientation as portrait / landscape, then draw that when you have a post with a featured image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic check of aspect ratio. Display as landscape, square or portrait

```
if ( !has_post_thumbnail()) { 
    return 'Error'; 
} else {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '');
    $image_w = $image[1];
    $image_h = $image[2];

    if ($image_w > $image_h) { 
        echo 'landscape';
    }
    elseif ($image_w == $image_h) { 
        echo 'square';
    }
    else { 
        echo 'portrait';
    } 
}
```